# Could not find gem 'jquery-rails (~> 1.1.6) ruby' in the gems available on this machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gemfile, social-stream

I am trying to implement Social-stream with devise. when I am executing this rails generate social_stream:install. I am getting error Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "devise":
  In Gemfile:
    social_stream (>= 0) ruby depends on
      devise (~> 1.1.3) ruby

```
devise (2.2.3)
```

After I bundle update 
Then the error comes like this

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /home/cis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for gcc... yes
checking for Magick-config... no
Can't install RMagick 2.13.2. Can't find Magick-config in /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin:/home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/bin:/home/cis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin:/home/cis/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/cis/.rvm/bin

*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/cis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby


Gem files will remain installed in /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rmagick-2.13.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing rmagick (2.13.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rmagick -v '2.13.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

After solving the dependency stuff   I am getting

```
/home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/devise-1.1.9/lib/devise.rb:193:in `mailer=': undefined method `ref' for ActiveSupport::Dependencies:Module (NoMethodError)
    from /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/devise-1.1.9/lib/devise.rb:195:in `<module:Devise>'
    from /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/devise-1.1.9/lib/devise.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
    from /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
    from /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
    from /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
    from /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
    from /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /home/cis/test_app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:24:in `require'
    from /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:24:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>
```

I tried sorting out dependency of Jquery rails with social_stream but it also didn't work out
Plz help me sort out this chain of errors

Answer (score 0):

Social Stream is not currently compatible with Devise's last version. Patches are welcomed. See issue at https://github.com/ging/social_stream/issues/335